# Constructing array from elements of another array neatly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, splice

I am wondering how to do the following more cleanly and in the general case. I'm constructing the array `final_array_transpose` with elements from another array, imb_data (currently has length 5 but can have any length). Here's what I have for the `len=5` case.

```
final_array_transpose = np.array([ 
        imb_data[0].copy(), 
        imb_data[1].copy(), 
        imb_data[2].copy(), 
        imb_data[3].copy(), 
        imb_data[4].copy(), 
        bin_label_str, 
        range(len(imb_data[0])), 
        bin_label_str,
        bin_label,
        bin_label],       
    dtype = object)
```

(Ignore everything past `imb_data[4].copy()`)

How do I generalize this for any length of `imb_data` (imb_data is a 2D array)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the whole array and use unpacking:

```
final_array_transpose = np.array([ 
        *imb_data.copy(), 
        bin_label_str, 
        range(len(imb_data[0])), 
        bin_label_str,
        bin_label,
        bin_label],       
    dtype = object)
```

If you want the entire array in `imb_data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to loop over all of `imb_data`.

```
final_array_transpose = np.array(
    [x.copy() for x in imb_data] + [
        bin_label_str, 
        range(len(imb_data[0])), 
        bin_label_str,
        bin_label,
        bin_label
    ],
    dtype = object)
```